# Where to process data in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Back when I was using CodeIgniter I had functions in my models like

```
 public function GetArticlesFormatted($inactive = FALSE)
```

and then in my controller I could have had

```
 $articles->GetArticlesFormatted(true);
```

And so on.

How should I achieve the same with Laravel 5.4? The database of the app I'm building is already built and full and is a mess so most of the "automated" super-restrictive things that Laravel has don't work out of the box.

For example there is a Country Code that I'm retrieving and I need it as is, but in some instances I need it converted in a Country Name which I had in another table.

Right now I just have in my controller wherever I am retrieving data from the model:

```
  $countryResult = Country::where('country_code', $item['country_code'])->first();
  $countryArray = $countryResult->toArray();
  $item['country'] = $countryArray['country_name'];
```

Can I somehow achieve that in a more elegant way?
I tried accessors but for some reason couldn't get anything to work for my purposes.

Comment: For that code example, does this work? `$item['country'] = Country::where(...)->first()->country_name;`. By the way, what's `$item`? Is it some array you will respond with?

Comment: `$item` is an array that is later sent to the view by this controller.

Comment: I also wanted to point that normally, Laravel shapes your workflow and database, but in your case you have to shape Laravel to match the db you're working with, thus, as you more or less said, you can't strictly follow Laravel's `standards`, so do as you need. E.g. need more code on Models? Just do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A select query can be used to limit selection to a particular column.

```
$countryName = Country::select('country_name')
               ->where('country_code', $item['country_code'])
               ->first();
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but can I somehow put and reference a large chunk of code in a model, so that I can do a simple one-line call of that whole data process in my controller?

Or should it just stay in the controller? I can see this being "standard" but that kind of defeats the purpose of Models in my case since I want to to able to `->fetchForDashboard()` in my Controller and the Model to take care of it.

Comment: Sure you can move this to a static method in your model that makes this query or better implement a repository for your model and implement that in your repository

Comment: Awesome! Repositories is something I was not familiar with. Seems like it's going to be the thing I'm looking for.